# PHP - spl_autoload lowercasing class names

Tags: php, autoload

I'm trying to use `spl_autoload()` to autoload namespaced classes, where the folder structure follows namespaces, without implementing my own autoloader. I've followed [this comment on the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php#92767). However, it lowercases the class name to find its file, which is a shame as I'd like the filenames to follow class names... Is there any way to work around this without implementing a custom autoloader?

P.S. (feel free to remove this) : how is this not documented, does everyone working with PHP use a case-insensitive filesystem?

Comment: There's no comment in the link you shared. Can you instead just show the actual code you tried?

Comment: You've linked the PHP 8 release notes :-? The first argument for [spl_autoload()](https://php.net/spl_autoload) is described as *the lowercased name of the class (and namespace) being instantiated.*

Comment: Usually people who implement autoloading with PHP use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php with a [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) compliant autoload function which is required to be case sensitive.

Comment: apokryfos and Álvaro González, oops, that's the wrong link. Fixed it. I'm using PHP 7.4 btw.

Comment: Well... It *is* documented (open your link and scroll up) and that's how the default implementation works. If it doesn't fulfil your needs you can write your own (it isn't too hard). The user who left the comment was most certainly using Windows thus his comment with `My.class.php` rather than `my.class.php`. In any case, beware that checking the entire include path for classes can easily defeat any purported performance gain.